When does flipping a weighted coin produce more $H^aT^b$ or $H^bT^a$ sequences than an unbiased coin?
I came across the following remark in a research paper:

"We flip a coin $a+b$ times, looking for either the sequence $H^aT^b$ or $H^bT^a$. If our coin lands heads with probability $p$, the chance of success is $p^a(1-b)^b + p^b(1-p)^a$. Note that an unbiased coin will not always maximize this probability, for instance when $(a-b)^2 > a+b$. Furthermore, if $a, b \to \infty$ and $a >> b$ then the optimal weight is $p \sim \frac{a}{a+b}$."

I agree with the formula for the probability of success, but I do not understand where the condition $(a-b)^2 > a+b$ comes from (and of course, no proof is offered). The claim seems to be true experimentally (for instance, if $a=5$ and $b=2$ then $p = \frac{5}{7}$ succeeds with probability $(\frac{5}{7})^5(\frac{2}{7})^2 + (\frac{2}{7})^5(\frac{5}{7})^2 > 0.16 > 0.015625 = (\frac{1}{2})^7+(\frac{1}{2})^7$) but I've struggled to prove the claim in general.
I tried taking the derivative of $f(p) = p^a(1-b)^b + p^b(1-p)^a$ but I could not find extrema in the general case. I also tried using convexity and arithmetic-geometric means inequalities to no avail. It's not clear to me how the $(a-b)^2 > a+b$ condition should even come up in the calculations.

Check $f''(p)$ at $p=\frac{1}{2}$.

Thank you so much!

Thank you to user51547 for the answer! Taking $f''(p)$ at $p = \frac{1}{2}$ gives $(\frac{1}{2})^{a+b-1}[(a-b)^2 - (a+b)]$, so when $(a-b)^2 > a+b$, $f$ is concave up at $p = \frac{1}{2}$ and therefore not maximized there. Brilliant!
